# How to properly use tf.metrics.accuracy?

Tags: tensorflow

I have some trouble using the `accuracy` function from `tf.metrics` for a multiple classification problem with logits as input.

My model output looks like:

```
logits = [[0.1, 0.5, 0.4],
          [0.8, 0.1, 0.1],
          [0.6, 0.3, 0.2]]
```

And my labels are one hot encoded vectors:

```
labels = [[0, 1, 0],
          [1, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 1]]
```

When I try to do something like `tf.metrics.accuracy(labels, logits)` it never gives the correct result. I am obviously doing something wrong but I can't figure what it is.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**TL;DR**

The accuracy function [tf.metrics.accuracy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/accuracy) calculates how often predictions matches labels based on two local variables it creates: `total` and `count`, that are used to compute the frequency with which `logits` matches `labels`.

```
acc, acc_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=tf.argmax(labels, 1), 
                                  predictions=tf.argmax(logits,1))

print(sess.run([acc, acc_op]))
print(sess.run([acc]))
# Output
#[0.0, 0.66666669]
#[0.66666669]
```

- acc (accuracy): simply returns the metrics using `total` and `count`, doesnt update the metrics.
- acc_op (update up): updates the metrics.

To understand why the acc returns `0.0`, go through the details below.

---

**Details using a simple example:**

```
logits = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [2,3])
labels = tf.Variable([[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]])

acc, acc_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=tf.argmax(labels, 1),   
                                  predictions=tf.argmax(logits,1))
```

***Initialize the variables:***

Since `metrics.accuracy` creates two local variables `total` and `count`, we need to call `local_variables_initializer()` to initialize them.

```
sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

stream_vars = [i for i in tf.local_variables()]
print(stream_vars)

#[<tf.Variable 'accuracy/total:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>,
# <tf.Variable 'accuracy/count:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>]
```

***Understanding update ops and accuracy calculation:***

```
print('acc:',sess.run(acc, {logits:[[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]}))
#acc: 0.0

print('[total, count]:',sess.run(stream_vars)) 
#[total, count]: [0.0, 0.0]
```

The above returns 0.0 for accuracy as `total` and `count` are zeros, inspite of giving matching inputs.

```
print('ops:', sess.run(acc_op, {logits:[[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]})) 
#ops: 1.0

print('[total, count]:',sess.run(stream_vars)) 
#[total, count]: [2.0, 2.0]
```

With the new inputs, the accuracy is calculated when the update op is called. Note: since all the logits and labels match, we get accuracy of 1.0 and the local variables `total` and `count` actually give `total correctly predicted` and the `total comparisons made`.

Now we call `accuracy` with the new inputs (not the update ops):

```
print('acc:', sess.run(acc,{logits:[[1,0,0],[0,1,0]]}))
#acc: 1.0
```

Accuracy call doesnt update the metrics with the new inputs, it just returns the value using the two local variables. Note: the logits and labels dont match in this case. Now calling update ops again:

```
print('op:',sess.run(acc_op,{logits:[[0,1,0],[0,1,0]]}))
#op: 0.75 
print('[total, count]:',sess.run(stream_vars)) 
#[total, count]: [3.0, 4.0]
```

The metrics are updated to new inputs

---

For more information on how to use the metrics during training and how to reset them during validation, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50745126/resetting-tensorflow-streaming-metrics-variables/50746989#50746989).

Comment: You want to get the maximum along the last dimension, so it should be `tf.argmax(logits, 1)` and `tf.argmax(labels,1)`

Comment: And I think you got `labels` and `predictions` mixed around

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled about why do you have to run `acc` operation twice? When I tested this code it does seem to appear that you need to do that otherwise the acc won't contain the accuracy tensor despite the documentation clearly saying:

`accuracy: A Tensor representing the accuracy, the value of total divided by count`

Comment: @gyre You can find the explanation [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3971) but the bottom line is that work is being done on making it more intuitive. `tf.contrib.metrics.accuracy` seems to work better.

Comment: keep in mind that only `acc_op ` actually computes the accuracy from the values of logits and labels, while `acc` returns the overall accuracy. So to validate a batch use `acc_op` -> https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15115

Comment: As @dperalta mentioned, it has be 1st axis so be cautious!

Comment: I find this [link](http://ronny.rest/blog/post_2017_09_11_tf_metrics/) very helpful to understand what the **tf.metrics.accuracy()** actually do.

Answer (score 5):

On TF 2.0, if you are using the tf.keras API, you can define a custom class myAccuracy which inherits from tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy, and overrides the update method like this:

```py
# imports
# ...
class myAccuracy(tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy):
    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_true = tf.argmax(y_true,1)
        y_pred = tf.argmax(y_pred,1)
        return super(myAccuracy,self).update_state(y_true,y_pred,sample_weight)
```

Then, when compiling the model you can add metrics in the usual way.

```py
from my_awesome_models import discriminador

discriminador.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                      loss=tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits,
                      metrics=[myAccuracy()])

from my_puzzling_datasets import train_dataset,test_dataset

discriminador.fit(train_dataset.shuffle(70000).repeat().batch(1000), 
                  epochs=1,steps_per_epoch=1, 
                  validation_data=test_dataset.shuffle(70000).batch(1000), 
                  validation_steps=1)

# Train for 1 steps, validate for 1 steps
# 1/1 [==============================] - 3s 3s/step - loss: 0.1502 - accuracy: 0.9490 - val_loss: 0.1374 - val_accuracy: 0.9550
```

Or evaluate yout model over the whole dataset

```py
discriminador.evaluate(test_dataset.batch(TST_DSET_LENGTH))
#> [0.131587415933609, 0.95354694]
```

Answer (score 2):

Applied on a cnn you can write:

```
x_len=24*24
y_len=2

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, x_len], name='input')

fc1 = ... # cnn's fully connected layer
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob')
layer_fc_dropout = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, keep_prob, name='dropout')

y_pred = tf.nn.softmax(fc1, name='output')
logits = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)

y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, y_len], name='y_true')
acc, acc_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=tf.argmax(y_true, axis=1), predictions=tf.argmax(y_pred, 1))


sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

def print_accuracy(x_data, y_data, dropout=1.0):
    accuracy = sess.run(acc_op, feed_dict = {y_true: y_data, x: x_data, keep_prob: dropout})
    print('Accuracy: ', accuracy)
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending the answer to TF2.0, the tutorial here explains clearly how to use tf.metrics for accuracy and loss.
https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/quickstart/advanced

Notice that it mentions that the metrics are reset after each epoch :

```py
  train_loss.reset_states()
  train_accuracy.reset_states()
  test_loss.reset_states()
  test_accuracy.reset_states()
```

When label and predictions are one-hot-coded

```py
def train_step(features, labels):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        prediction = model(features)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=predictions))
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_weights)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_weights))
    train_loss(loss)
    train_accuracy(tf.argmax(labels, 1), tf.argmax(predictions, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how I use it:

```py
test_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()

# use dataset api or normal dataset from lists/np arrays
ds_test_batch = zip(x_test,y_test)

predicted_classes =  np.array([])

for (x, y) in ds_test_batch:
  # training=False is needed only if there are layers with different
  # behaviour during training versus inference (e.g. Dropout).
  
  #Ajust the input similar to your input during the training 
  logits =  model(x.reshape(1,-1), training=False ) 
  prediction = tf.argmax(logits, axis=1, output_type=tf.int64)
  
  predicted_classes =  np.concatenate([predicted_classes,prediction.numpy()])
  
  test_accuracy(prediction, y)

print("Test set accuracy: {:.3%}".format(test_accuracy.result()))
```