# Meaning of values returned by tensorflow accuracy metric

Tags: python, tensorflow, metrics

I'm a bit confused about the values returned by the functions of the module tf.metrics (for example [tf.metrics.accuracy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/accuracy)).

A simple piece of code in which I calculate accuracy using tf.metrics.accuracy and using tp, tn, fp and fn.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# true and predicted tensors
y_p = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int64)
y_t = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int64)

# Count true positives, true negatives, false positives and false negatives.
tp = tf.count_nonzero(y_p * y_t)
tn = tf.count_nonzero((y_p - 1) * (y_t - 1))
fp = tf.count_nonzero(y_p * (y_t - 1))
fn = tf.count_nonzero((y_p - 1) * y_t)

acc = tf.metrics.accuracy(y_p, y_t)

# Calculate accuracy, precision, recall and F1 score.
accuracy = (tp + tn) / (tp + fp + fn + tn)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

    for i in range(4):
        if i == 0:
            yop = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        elif i == 1:
            yop = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1]
        elif i == 2:
            yop = [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
        else:
            yop = [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
        tf_a = sess.run(acc, feed_dict={y_p: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], y_t: yop})
        my_a = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={y_p: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], y_t: yop})
        print("TF accuracy: {0}".format(tf_a))
        print("My accuracy: {0}".format(my_a))
```

which outputs

```
TF accuracy: (0.0, 1.0)
My accuracy: 1.0
TF accuracy: (1.0, 0.9)
My accuracy: 0.8
TF accuracy: (0.9, 0.8)
My accuracy: 0.6
TF accuracy: (0.8, 0.7)
My accuracy: 0.4
```

I understand that the second returned value of tf.metrics.accuracy (the update_op) is the averaged accuracy over the number of times the function was called. However, I can't make sense of the first value, which should represent the accuracy. Why does it differ from the value of the accuracy I calculate myself? Isn't there a way to obtain the non-cumulative value for the accuracy?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

# true and predicted tensors
y_p = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int64)
y_t = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int64)

# Count true positives, true negatives, false positives and false negatives.
tp = tf.count_nonzero(y_p * y_t)
tn = tf.count_nonzero((y_p - 1) * (y_t - 1))
fp = tf.count_nonzero(y_p * (y_t - 1))
fn = tf.count_nonzero((y_p - 1) * y_t)

acc = tf.metrics.accuracy(predictions=y_p, labels=y_t)

# Calculate accuracy, precision, recall and F1 score.
accuracy = (tp + tn) / (tp + fp + fn + tn)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(4):
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())


        if i == 0:
            yop = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        elif i == 1:
            yop = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1]
        elif i == 2:
            yop = [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
        else:
            yop = [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
        print('accuracy_score', accuracy_score([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], yop))
        tf_a = sess.run(acc, feed_dict={y_p: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], y_t: yop})
        my_a = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={y_p: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], y_t: yop})
        print("TF accuracy: {0}".format(tf_a))
        print("My accuracy: {0}".format(my_a))
        print()
```

output:

```
accuracy_score 1.0
TF accuracy: (0.0, 1.0)
My accuracy: 1.0

accuracy_score 0.8
TF accuracy: (0.0, 0.8)
My accuracy: 0.8

accuracy_score 0.6
TF accuracy: (0.0, 0.6)
My accuracy: 0.6

accuracy_score 0.4
TF accuracy: (0.0, 0.4)
My accuracy: 0.4
```

Simply moving the `tf.local_variables_initializer()` inside the loop makes sure that the values in accuracy metric tensor get's re-initialised.

**Why does it work?**

As per the documentation

> The accuracy function creates two local variables, total and count
>   that are used to compute the frequency with which predictions matches
>   labels.

If we don't reinitialise the local variables then value from previous iteration remains in it, leading to wrong results as you were experiencing.

The other approach is to use:

`tf.contrib.metrics.accuracy` instead of `tf.metrics.accuracy`. But this gives some residual value at the end like `0.800000011920929` instead of `0.8`. It's also [deprecated](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.6/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/metrics/streaming_accuracy) as pointed out by OP in comments.

Source:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/accuracy

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3971

[How to properly use tf.metrics.accuracy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46409626/how-to-properly-use-tf-metrics-accuracy)

Comment: Thanks, moving the initialization operation inside the loop did the trick indeed. Then, the first value returned is the previous value of the averaged accuracy (therefore, it is equal to `0.0` after re-initialization). Still not sure why someone would need that instead of the actual value of the accuracy though. As a note, `tf.contrib.metrics.accuracy` seems to be [deprecated](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.6/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/metrics/streaming_accuracy)

Comment: Cool, I will add that information to the Answer. Work is on going on `tf.metrics.accuracy` as per what i have read, discussions to make it more intuitive.

Comment: @pangasio But that answered your question right ? the initialisation part?

Comment: Understood. Yes, it did answer my question and I marked it as the accepted answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks @pangasio :)