# Resetting tensorflow streaming metrics' variables

Tags: python, tensorflow, metrics

I have a bunch of streaming metrics (`tf.metrics.accuracy` and [custom](http://vict0rsch.github.io/2018/06/06/tensorflow-streaming-multilabel-f1/) streaming `micro`, `macro` and `weighted` F1-scores).

During training, I get the kind of plot below (nevermind the overfitting).

This happens because to compute the validation set's metrics I call `tf.local_variables_initializer` to reset the metrics and only have a value for the validation set.

This implies 2 side effects:

1. The spikes in the image
2. In between validations, training metrics keep aggregating even if validation happens every 2 epochs

I could partially solve the situation by having different tensors hold each metric (train vs val). But It would not solve `2.`

I therefore have **2 questions**:

- In your experience, is it a behavior you expect to see (or not? solution?)
- Is there a way to have metrics stream only over the last `n` batches?

[image: spkinging plot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behaviour is expected if you reset the metrics in between training. 
The train metrics dont agregrate the validation metrics if they are two different ops. I will give an example on how to keep those metrics different and how to reset only one of them.

---

**A toy Example:**

```
logits = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [2,3])
labels = tf.Variable([[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]])

#create two different ops
with tf.name_scope('train'):
   train_acc, train_acc_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=tf.argmax(labels, 1), 
                                                 predictions=tf.argmax(logits,1))
with tf.name_scope('valid'):
   valid_acc, valid_acc_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=tf.argmax(labels, 1), 
                                                 predictions=tf.argmax(logits,1))
```

**Training:**

```
#initialize the local variables has it holds the variables used for metrics calculation.
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# initial state
print(sess.run(train_acc, {logits:[[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]}))
print(sess.run(valid_acc, {logits:[[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]}))

#0.0
#0.0
```

The initial states are `0.0` as expected.

Now calling the training op metrics:

```
#training loop
for _ in range(10):
    sess.run(train_acc_op, {logits:[[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]})  
print(sess.run(train_acc, {logits:[[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]}))
# 1.0
print(sess.run(valid_acc, {logits:[[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]}))
# 0.0
```

Only the training accuracy got updated while the valid accuracy is still `0.0`. Calling the valid ops:

```
for _ in range(10):
    sess.run(valid_acc_op, {logits:[[0,1,0],[0,1,0]]}) 
print(sess.run(valid_acc, {logits:[[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]}))
#0.5
print(sess.run(train_acc, {logits:[[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]}))
#1.0
```

Here the valid accuracy got updated to a new value while the training accuracy remained unchanged.

Lets reset only the validation ops:

```
stream_vars_valid = [v for v in tf.local_variables() if 'valid/' in v.name]
sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(stream_vars_valid))

print(sess.run(valid_acc, {logits:[[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]}))
#0.0
print(sess.run(train_acc, {logits:[[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]}))
#1.0
```

The valid accuracy got reset to zero while the training accuracy remained unchanged.

Comment: However doing so prevents me from visualizing the accuracies on the same graph does it not?

Comment: why does the above prevent in visualising the accuracies on the same graph?.

Comment: I mean on the same plot, because they are different variables then. I may be wrong but it seems that the only way to put two graphs on the same plot is to log the same variables to 2 different writers otherwise they are logged separately