# tf.metrics.accuracy doesn't match real accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to reproduce the NN exercises of Coursera ML course using TensorFlow (and not Keras).

I find that calculating the accuracy using `tf.metrics.accuracy` gives results that are lower than the accuracy when I calculate it.

Relevant code is:

```
accuracy, update_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=y, predictions=tf.argmax(tf.sigmoid(output), axis=1))
...
# in session:
acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={tf_x: X, tf_y: y})
sess.run(update_op, feed_dict={tf_x: X, tf_y: y})
print(f'step {step} - accuracy: {acc}')
...
# real accuracy
predictions = sess.run(tf.argmax(tf.sigmoid(output), axis=1), feed_dict={tf_x: X})
pred_y = predictions == y
print(f'Training Set Accuracy after training: {np.mean(pred_y) * 100}%')
```

It can be even 30% difference (i.e. acc is 0.5 and real accuracy is 0.8)

Am I doing something wrong?

Note that if I do this:

```
equal = tf.equal(tf.cast(tf.argmax(tf.sigmoid(output), 1), tf.int32), y)
acc_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(equal, tf.float32))
acc = sess.run(acc_op, feed_dict={tf_x: X, tf_y: y})
```

I get the same results... so is tf.metrics.accuracy calculated in some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: First call `sess.run(update_op, feed_dict)`, then `sess.run(accuracy)`. If feeding a new batch, and accuracy *on that batch* is desired, some hidden vars must first be reset - the workflow's as follows:

```
accuracy, update_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(tf_labels, tf_predictions, scope="my_metrics")
running_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES, scope="my_metrics")
running_vars_initializer = tf.variables_initializer(var_list=running_vars)
```

```
for i in range(num_batches):
    # explicitly initialize/reset 'total' and 'count' to 0
    sess.run(running_vars_initializer) 

    # feed labels and predictions at i-th batch to update_ops
    feed_dict={tf_labels: y[i], tf_predictions: tf.argmax(tf.sigmoid(output[i]), axis=1)}
    session.run(update_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)

    # compute and print accuracy from current 'total' and 'count'
    print('Batch {} accuracy: {}'.format(i, session.run(accuracy)))
```

---

**DETAILS**: `tf.metrics.accuracy` utilizes two runtime variables, `total` (# of correct predictions) and `count` (# of labels fed), initialized locally behind the scenes. `accuracy` gets updated *only* once `update_op` is called - in steps:

- `total` and `count` are initialized to zero
- `sess.run(update_op, feed_dict)` --> `total` and `count` are updated per `feed_dict`
- `sess.run(accuracy)` --> `accuracy` uses the *current* `total` and `count` to compute the metric
- `sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict)` --> `accuracy` uses the *current* `total` and `count` to compute the metric

What the last two say is, `feed_dict` actually does nothing to change `accuracy`; `accuracy` operates on `total` and `count`, which are only updated via `update_op`. Lastly,

- `sess.run(accuracy, ...)` does *not* reset `total` and `count` to 0

This is largely why `total` and `count` are used at all - for *scalability*; it enables computing metrics of data too big to fit into memory in one go, by keeping a running history.

Lastly, your placeholder logic looks off - you feed data into `tf_x` and `tf_y`, yet neither are to be found anywhere within `tf.metrics.accuracy(...)` - but that's an easy fix.

---

**References/further reading**: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46409626/how-to-properly-use-tf-metrics-accuracy), a good [blog entry](http://ronny.rest/blog/post_2017_09_11_tf_metrics/)

Comment: So the problem was that I didn't re-initialize the local variables before each step. BTW - you don't have to use the local scope, you can instead use `init_local = tf.local_variables_initializer()` and call `sess.run(init_local)` for every step. (Unless you have other reasons to stick to a specific scope). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DavidRefaeli There is, in fact, a reason against it - it also reinitializes _other_ variables, which you may not intend to. This exacerbates for more involved applications, so good habit to explicitly target tensors - else may get entangled in the tensor-webs. Glad the problem's solved.